# JIRA - Design a screen having custom field with multiple inputs

Tags: jira, custom-fields, jira-plugin

Can we design a screen which allows to add multiple values for a custom field and it looks like form as shown in attached snap.

(table border is added just for refernece to distribuguish fields)
Please let me know how it could be achievable or any alternative approach way.[image]

Thanks

Dhaval Soni

Answer (score 0):

you can create HTML table as you like and append to any text area field

Comment: How can we add custom field having HTML table in JIRA. can you add some details or stuff example, please ?